# Compile and Debug GLUT under Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am developing an application which makes use of OpenGL. In order to do so, I'd really like to dig and debug GLUT in order to see the source code that is called under each function of GLUT and debug it.

I've downloaded the source files of GLUT, which come with a Makefile, however Visual Studio 2010, when trying to convert it fails. I've googled for this but no one seems to explain how to do it, with the disadvantage that GLUT is quite old.

Does anybody know how can I add GLUT as a project into Visual Studio (I prefer 2010) in order to debug it while running applications which make use of GLUT functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [freegult](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) - it comes with a Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 solution and project files. So it should be rathter easy for you to integrate it into your project. Freegult provides the same API as the original GLUT lib written by Mark Kilgard.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend moving away from glut and freeglut. [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) is much more modern and easier to understand. Is more commonly used than GLUT and is supported on more platforms. If you download the binaries from their site you will be able to link and include it as normal. Otherwise use can use [premake4](http://industriousone.com/premake) to generate a vs2010 project to build it.

Also which loading library are you using?

Edit. If you download the [glsdk](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html). You will be able to generate a vs2010 project using [premake4](http://industriousone.com/premake). You will then be able to run the example projects. Both GLUT and GLFW examples are provided and will run right out the box.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I am not planning at all to use any of these existing libraries. I am building a far more complex application. However, I need to perfectly understand some sequences of calling routiones of OpenGL. For that, I've taken CEGUI as an example and I was debugging their code, and many examples use GLUT. The idea is that I can recognise and understand Step-by-step each line of the code, that's why I needed to debug GLUT.
In the future, I do not plan to use GLUT at all